# Apache Mina UDP Server Send Messages to Client

Tags: java, networking, client-server, apache-mina

Apache Mina UDP Server Send Messages to Client +code, any one have sample code for that can u send it ?

Comment: Here on SO you are expected to present some code snippet you are having trouble with.  If it's a more generic question then you are expected to take your time to at least google your question.  For your information, the link I posted in my answer was the first hit when searching for "Apache Mina UDP Server".  Please read the guidelines to this platform: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 2):

What about the [tutorial in the official documentation](http://mina.apache.org/udp-tutorial.html)?  Have you had a look at it?

Comment: @user523534: "not working" is not a proper description.  Please try to assemble things to a certain point and describe your problem *exactly*.  It may well be the case that you are not having trouble with Apache Mina at all, but Java programming in general.  Maybe you just need to know how to actually compile and run the code...  Maybe...  So please describe the issue in as much detail as you can.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/mina/trunk/) is there subversion address. In it you will find an example directory full of [examples](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/mina/trunk/mina-example/src/main/java/org/apache/mina/example/). I hope this helps.